# Subtracting value from value above under certain conditions - no loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to get a balance value from a df that looks like this

```
df1

Name   Year    Ch1    Origin
A      1995    x1      a
A      1996    x2      b
A      1997    x3      a
A      2000    x4      a
B      1997    y1      c
B      1998    y2      c
```

while Ch1 is numerical. and I want to add an extra col to have this value:

```
Name   Year   Ch1    Bil
A      1995    x1    
A      1996    x2    %
A      1997    x3    %
A      2000    x4    %
B      1997    y1  
B      1998    y2    %
```

I want "Bil" to be 
- X2/X1 (value from previous year divided by recent year) IF X2>X1
- -X1/X2 IF X1

```
for (i in nrow(df1))
  if (df[i,1]==df[i-1,1]) {
      if (df[i,3]>df[i-1,3] {
          df$Bil<-(df[i,3]/df[i-1,3])
      } else df$Bil<-(-df[i-1,3]/df[i,3])
  }
```

Is there a more elegant or quicker way to calculate this? This way I really need to make sure that the dataset is in the right order (going from older to recent years). Let's say also dependent on an extra detail such as origin so that the calculation only happens if name and origin are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R code which applied `ave` + `pmax`. Hope the code below can reach your objective

```
df <- within(df,Bill <- ave(Ch1,Name,FUN = function(v) c(NA,sign(v[-1]-v[-length(v)])*pmax(v[-1]/v[-length(v)],v[-length(v)]/v[-1]))))
```

such that

```
> df
  Name Year Ch1 Origin      Bill
1    A 1995  11      a        NA
2    A 1996  12      b  1.090909
3    A 1997   3      a -4.000000
4    A 2000  14      a  4.666667
5    B 1997  21      c        NA
6    B 1998  12      c -1.750000
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Year = c(1995L, 
1996L, 1997L, 2000L, 1997L, 1998L), Ch1 = c(11L, 12L, 3L, 14L, 
21L, 12L), Origin = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: The code does the inverse of what I want. 
If V-1 < V I want Ch1(V)/Ch1(v-1)
if V-1> V I want - Ch1(V-1)/Ch(V)

In your solution this is correctly solved in my calculation it does the inverse

Comment: It works now BUT
if V-1> V I want - Ch1(V-1)/Ch(V)
this value is still not negative

Comment: @antonina did you see the output in my answer? for row 3 and 6, they are negative values, i.e.,  - Ch1(V-1)/Ch(V)

Comment: yes sorry! Works now i restarted the code! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry I have to ask again! IS the case V-1==V omitted in this calculation? A balance would not be created?

Comment: @antonina no, I don't think it i omitted, since `pmax(1,1)` will give `1`

Comment: how can I include this in V-1>= V I want - Ch1(V-1)/Ch(V) ?

Comment: And i know you changed this because I asked you for it, but if I want  V-1 < V I want -Ch1(V)/Ch1(v-1) if V-1>= V I want Ch1(V-1)/Ch(V) 
Where exactly would I have to change the sign?

Comment: @antonina I guess you can try `sign(v[-length(v)]-v[-1])*pmax(v[-1]/v[-length(v)],v[-length(v)]/v[-1])`